# Excel Query Prompt for User Input

Tags: vba, excel

Simply put, I'd like to be able to prompt the user for a parameter that would then be used in the SQL Query to return data. (ie, rather than return all values, only return values based on the user input). This could be a msgbox or cell value.

Comment: I haven't found anyway to modify the sql query from VBA. Or would I be wanting to have the query contain a parameter that Excel knows to prompt for every time that data connection is refreshed?

Comment: So apparently all that needs to be done is put in "?" for the criteria. As such:'WHERE (matltran.item Like ?)'

Comment: in which situation you use it- with QueryTable, with ADO or in other situation?

Answer (score 2):

the vb(a) function [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) might serve your need.

Comment: I think I phrased the question poorly. I know how to get the data, just don't know how to use it.